# MVC Calendar pops up when checkbox clicked

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, checkbox, calendar

The calendar control pops up when clicking the checkbox.  This is a ASP.NET Zero, ASP.NET Boilerplate project.  The latest date control selected will reappear when the checkbox is clicked.  Any clue as to why the calendar pops up when the checkbox is clicked?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date1, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date", @class = "form-control", id = "Date1"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date2, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date", @class = "form-control", id = "Date2" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ISChecked, new { @class = "icheck", id = "Checkbox1" })
```

I don't haven enough reputation points to embed picture links:

Form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUXMc.jpg

Popup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMxyJ.jpg

Comment: Ask on [ASP.NET Zero support forum](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewforum.php?f=5).